# Downgrade Ventura 13.3.1 to Ventura 13.1

Tags: mac-osx, mouse

My new Mac Mini M2 has Ventura 13.3.1 pre-installed. Unfortunately, that MacOS version is notorious for the mouse stuttering/lagging. Both my bluetooth mouse and my Logitech mouse with dongle are nearly unusable. Only a wired mouse works normally.

I tried to install Monterey, but the installer hangs. Apparently there is no hardware support for the M2.

Going by the many reports on Internet, Ventura 13.1 was still good, and the lag started when version 13.2 was rolled out. To try that, I created a bootable USB stick with Ventura 13.1. However, the installer requires an active internet connection. And guess what... during the install it automatically downloads the latest version 13.3.1 and ignores version 13.1 on the USB stick.

How can I install 13.1? Can I somehow force an offline install? Can I block the automatic upgrade?

Comment: Your question is much better suited for the Apple / Mac specific sister site https://apple.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @HBruijn thanks. Wasn't aware that site existed. There are so many stackoverflow sites nowadays.